# There is a weird symbol coming below the bootstrap caret icon. How to fix this?

Tags: html, css

I am making the homepage for a website, using a template. The template uses bootstrap 3. I added a dropdown menu to the navbar using the provided code here.

but this weird symbol pops up when I open the dropdown menu:
[image]

I have tried changing the dropdown from  to  and it seems to solve the problem but I need to use  and not button.

```
<li class="dropdown">
                           <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="more" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">MORE<span class="caret"></span></a>
                           <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                               <li><a href="#">Season 1</a></li>
                               <li><a href="#">Season 2</a></li>

                           </ul>
                       </li>
```

No error messages are shown in the console.

CSS code for the navbar which contains dropdown: https://pastebin.com/kZACAh7V

HTML code for the page: https://pastebin.com/EffYcypu

I solved it! this was the code that was causing problems in navbar.css:

```
.navbar-default .dropdown-menu::before {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -20.5px;
    right: 10px;
    font-family: "Icons";
    font-size: 18px;
    content: "\e030";
    color: white;
```

I removed the content line.

Comment: You need to provide more HTML and CSS if we are to see the issue with your code.

Comment: It looks like a broken icon from font like FontAwesome, please provide full code

Comment: It looks like the `<span class="caret"></span>` is the problem

Comment: @alessio i added the full code.

Comment: Make a JSfiddle, bootply rather than a pastebin, cause now we need to individually check, rather then seeing the result inmideatly

Comment: Yes also, all your assets have relative URLs so everything goes 404...

Comment: https://www.bootply.com/PLqGsmwNvv .. i cant reproduce your issue with the code you supplied. I am going to asume this issue is maybe in your css somewhere else, rather than just in your navbar. Somewhere it may use same class maybe.

Comment: okay @dorvalla so this gave me an idea and i checked with 2 other browsers and this issue did not occur there. It only occured in mozilla firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

```
    .body{
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #333;
    content: /e360
    }
```

I removed the content line from this and it was solved.